# Same Javascript code but not same act

Tags: javascript, host

//Edit

Hello.

I have made a website and uploaded to the host. So, the codes what are in my localhost and in the website host are same. Everything works except one JavaScript(jQuery) action(A dropdown menu). On my localhost it works perfect, on the website host, it drops and rises again and than doesn't drop again.

site : http://www.hastahakki.com/index.php?page=anasayfa

The problem on the big buttons like "Doğru Hastane Seçimi" , "Hasta Şikayetleri"

How do I do?

Comment: I am afraid magicians and oracles don't visit this site quite often. With such a question currently those are the type of persons capable of answering.

Comment: Please post some specifics: lines of code, browser and web server being used, etc., etc.

Comment: Which kind of web platform do you host your website? Do you use the absolute path or relative path of your jquery.js? Could you link to your jquery.js through your browser, for example http://{your site}/js/jquery.js?

Comment: site : http://www.hastahakki.com/index.php?page=anasayfa

Comment: @sundowatch I found your website works well as I visited it. The drop menu doesn't work only when you click the button too fast. That makes the **dropped** attribute of the **dddhs** div incorrect. So, the drop menus action incorrect when the next time you click the same button.

Comment: Post error message. Post relevant code. Post screenshot of weird/incorrect behaviour if required and explain what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's rare for pure client code to work differently in a hosted environment provided it is uploaded properly and the same browser is used.

First I would check it's not a cache issue by clearing my browser cache.

Then I would view it in a browser with modern developer tools, which is most browsers with the latest version (Firefox requires the excellent Firebug plugin). In Chrome for instance, looking at the Network output will show you if any resources are failing to load, and the Scripts view will show you any local JavaScript errors that might be triggered by the hosted version.